# Which PHP date formatting is this Mon Jun 27 13:59:36 +1000 2016

Tags: php, date, formatting, compare

As topic says, I'm looking for the date() markup of

```
Mon Jun 27 13:59:36 +1000 2016
```

I've got this so far but not getting the + in front of the forelast parameter.

```
date("D M d H:i:s Z Y");
```

which generates something like this:

```
Fri Jan 15 22:13:23 3600 2016
```

But I guess I need this + in order to be able to compare it with a future date like:

```
Mon Jun 27 13:59:36 +1000 2016
```

Any hints are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `O` rather than `Z` as outlined here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
echo date("D M d H:i:s O Y");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. Unfortunately the plus in front is still not showing. Any other ideas?

Comment: using `O` will add a plus or minus (depending on the timezone specified)

Comment: Thanks, I had some caching issue so the date was not showing properly. Answer is of course correct. Cheers